# Rules token one-time-login-url is showing up empty

Tags: 7, rules, tokens, actions

I have a rule that, after submitting a webform, a user gets created and then sends two emails to that user.  One saying their form data is being looked at by someone for review before they get a certain role, and another that gives them the one-time login url.  The problem is the that, while the rule works and both emails get sent, the login url is not displayed in the second email.

```
{ "rules_application_submission_affiliate" : {
    "LABEL" : "Application submission: Affiliate",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "webform_rules", "php" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "webform_has_id" : {
          "form_id" : "[form-id:value]",
          "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-101" : "webform-client-form-101" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "param_name" : "\u003C?php echo $data[\u0027components\u0027][\u0027your_username\u0027][\u0027value\u0027][0]; ?\u003E",
            "param_mail" : "\u003C?php echo $data[\u0027components\u0027][\u0027your_e_mail\u0027][\u0027value\u0027][0]; ?\u003E"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "new_user" : "New user" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "new-user" ] } },
      { "user_unblock" : { "account" : [ "new-user" ] } },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[data:your_e_mail-value]",
          "subject" : "Thank you for your application!",
          "message" : "Your application is being processed.  You will receive another email when your account is ready for activation.",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[new-user:mail]",
          "subject" : "Your account is ready!",
          "message" : "You may activate your account by going to this link to set your password:\r\n[new-user:one-time-login-url]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the "save entity" action, I had to force it to save by checking "force" on the action, because the entity would only get saved after the other actions had been applied.